# Use a formula that returns text, concatenating a number field

Tags: formula

I have the following problem:
I need to use a formula in my flow, which will be for my description field, text should appear in it and concatenate with a number type field. I receive the following error:

> Formula expression is invalid: Incorrect parameter type for '&' operator. Text was expected, Number was found

This is my formula:

```
"Order Number: " & ObterPedido.OrderNumber &
"Order value: R$" & ObterPedido.TotalAmount
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error is saying, `&` is one of the two *text* concatenation operators.

Numbers are not text.

So you need some way to convert `TotalAmount` from a number into text.

The `TEXT()` function does just that. Assuming the rest of your formula is fine (if you're creating this formula in the flow itself, I think you may be missing some curly braces), then the only thing you need to do here is change `ObterPedido.TotalAmount` to `TEXT(ObterPedido.TotalAmount)`

i.e. Use the `TEXT()` function, passing in a number, to get text as a result so that you can concatenate it with other strings.

For the future, your first port of call when working with formulas should be [the documentation on Formula Operators and Functions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.customize_functions.htm&type=5). It'll give you an idea of what things you can do, tell you how to use them, and there is often at least one example of how to use each thing.